# How i can clean cache programmatically for only one store?

Tags: multistore, cache, store-view, programming

How i can clean cache programmatically for only one store ?

and refresh index for only one store ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way since the cache is not related to a store but to the entire installation.
The same affirmation applies for indexes.

Comment: And if i modify all cache key, and i develop script for clean all key with this store id? :)

Comment: Sure, you can try that. At this moment is not possible nor explored as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

It's realy easy with store code and store id.

After check all cache key, you can clean

```
$storeCacheTag = strtoupper(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG.'_' . $store->getCode());
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean($storeCacheTag);
```